# Batch File - Using For & Xcopy Getting Invalid Number of Parameters (Not Quotes)?

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, xcopy

Basically what I'm trying to do is make a batch file that will run through the computer and grab everything from the Desktops and My Documents of ever user on the computer. Thing is, I won't know every users name because it will be used on unknown computers to back up. Trying to find a way to copy these things but so far I can not. I've been working on My Documents and I keep getting a "Invalid number of parameters".

```
@echo off
echo This script will copy all of the files from my documents onto a C drive.
pause
md "C:\TestForWork"
pause
for /D /r %%G in ("C:\Users") DO for /D /r "%%H" in ("%%G\My Documents\") do xcopy %%H /e /y "C:\TestFor Work"
pause
```

Comment: Have you considered starting from the outer loop and seeing whether it even walks through all the users in `C:\Users`?  (hint:  it doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the first parameter to `xcopy` in double-quotes because it is a directory name containing spaces:

```
for /D /r %%G in ("C:\Users") DO (
    for /D /r %%H in ("%%~G\My Documents\") do (
        xcopy "%%~H" /e /y "C:\TestFor Work"
    )
)
```

You also need to use the `~` to prevent double-quotes from being included in the variable expansion.

Comment: It still does the same thing.

Comment: You didn't do what I suggested.  I have edited my answer to illustrate, and corrected another issue.

Comment: I'd be a little wary of those `/r` flags too.  Before you run a script like this, always test its sanity by putting `echo` in front of the `xcopy`.

Comment: I copied it literally to the letter and I still get invalid number of parameters.

Comment: Oh, and for some reason, it's only copying the Desktop files? No My Documents at all and I haven't mentioned or put in anything about the Desktop files.

Comment: Used echo and it shows three different instances of C:\ directories in one little area. How can this be?

Comment: Take away the `/r` from both loops.  I don't think any good can come of it.

Comment: Still get the same error message. It's needed actually or the program doesn't work the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /d %%u in ("c:\users\*") do for %%f in ("Desktop" "Documents") do (
    robocopy "%%~u\%%~f" "c:\test for work\%%~u\%%~f" /s
)
```

Or, for xcopy

```
for /d %%u in ("c:\users\*") do for %%f in ("Desktop" "Documents") do (
    xcopy "%%~u\%%~f" "c:\test for work\%%~u\%%~f" /e /y /i
)
```